# ADO.Net: Check if field name exists on IDataRecord

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there a better way for getting the field_name value from a IDataRecord only if the field_name exists in the IDataRecord, currently I'm using a **try{...} catch{...}** block, but this is some kind of *On Error Resume next*. Some alternatives?

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns column value from IDataRecord only if field_name exists.
/// </summary>
public static Tresult ValueIfExists<Tresult>(this IDataRecord record, string field_name)
{
    try { return record.Value<Tresult>(record.GetOrdinal(field_name)); }
    catch { return default(Tresult); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns column value from IDataRecord accecing by index.
/// </summary>
public static Tresult Value<Tresult>(this IDataRecord record, int field_index)
{
    return record.IsDBNull(field_index) ? default(Tresult) :
              (Tresult)Convert.ChangeType(record[field_index], typeof(Tresult));
}
```

I have changed my **ValueIfExists** function to reflect your ideas, so it looks like this:

```
public static Tresult ValueIfExists2<Tresult>(this IDataRecord record, string field_name)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < record.FieldCount; index++)
    {
        if (record.GetName(index).Equals(field_name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return record.Value<Tresult>(record.GetOrdinal(field_name));
        }
    }
    return default(Tresult);
}
```

Comment: you should use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as columnnames can be in any case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting if an IDataReader contains a certain field before iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952/detecting-if-an-idatareader-contains-a-certain-field-before-iteration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are right that exceptions should not be used for normal program flow.

The `GetOrdinal` method is intended for situations where you know what fields you get, and if a field is missing that is an error that should result in an exception.

If you don't know which fields you get in the result, you should avoid the `GetOrdinal` method. You can instead get all the names and their index into a dictionary that you can use as replacement for the `GetOrdinal` method:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetAllNames(this IDataRecord record) {
  var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++) {
    result.Add(record.GetName(i), i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can use the `ContainsKey` method to check if the name exists in the dictionary, or the `TryGetValue` method to check if the name exists and get it's index it does in a single operation.

The `GetOrdinal` method first does a case sensetive search for the name, and if that fails it does a case insensetive search. That is not provided by the dictionary, so if you want that exact behaviour you would rather store the names in an array and write a method to loop through them when you want to find the index.

Comment: I think that [IDataRecord] interface is missing for a method for testing the elements existence. I have used something like your code for Visual Basic 6 recordsets, but I was of the idea that .Net have already something for dealing with this.

Comment: @ArceBrito: As far as I can tell there is no method for specifically checking the existance of a field in the implementation classes like `SqlDataReader` either. You just have to use `GetName` to find out which fields there are.

Comment: A more LINQy version: `Enumerable.Range(0, record.FieldCount).ToDictionary(i => record.GetName(i), i => i)`

Answer (score 3):

With one line:

```
bool exists = Enumerable.Range(0, dataRecord.FieldCount).Any(x => dataRecord.GetName(x) == "columnName"); // or with OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this closely-related question for a viable approach of testing for a field's existence. Note that if you are iterating a collection of results, it is probably better to check for the column once, rather than on each iteration.

[Check for column name in a SqlDataReader object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373230/check-for-column-name-in-a-sqldatareader-object)

Comment: It means that for now, the only manner for checking fields existence in the [IDataRecord] interface is iterating. Then the problem is to implement the best searching algorithm for IDataRecord.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following approach for `IDataReader` (since most `IDataRecord` you get are readers)
`reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Contains("field")`

Of course if you have a genuine `IDataRecord` then this will fail if you try to cast it to `IDataReader` and it isn't one.

Comment: In my case I'm using a Mapper pattern for creating objects by passing as argument the IDataRecord so I can't use your suggested approach; in the other hand it requires to get the database table metadata which could be more expensive than iterating over the fields collection with the purpose of checking field existence.

Comment: It's actually cheaper usually. The metadata was grabbed at least once in the case of the `SQLDataReader`, and it's cached afterwards, so it just keeps reading the same variable.

Comment: This checks the column in the schema table, not the actual data table! Always returns false! Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/813713/1070906